# Unity can't see the attached animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As stated in the title unity does not see the animation attached to it through the code, which in turn, this animation I put in the inspector

My player has a `BoxCollider2D` with `IsTrigger` ticked, so that it takes the value and runs

I put a check (already in the code) for the presence of animation, but he says exactly that he does not see

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CrackedPlatformScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public AnimationClip destroyed;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if(destroyed != null)
            {
                GetComponent<Animation>().Play(destroyed.name);
                gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
                Destroy(gameObject,0.4f);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(destroyed.name);
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you speaking about the `Animation` component from `GetComponent` or do you mean the `AnimationClip` referenced in `destroyed` ?

Comment: Also note that in the `else` part of your check `if(destroy != null)` the `destroy` is allways `null` so your last `Debug.Log` makes no sense .. in contrary this will **allways** through a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: The `GetComponent<Animation>()` you should not do here but rather in `Awake` and store the reference in a `private` variable to reuse it. You than should also check that one for `null` before using it or make sure the component is allways there by using `[RequireComponent(typeof(Animation))]` before your `public class ...` line

Comment: In `gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()...` didn't you want to use `other.gameObject...` ?

Comment: 1 I use `GetComponent` coz `animation` was out of date
2 The `destroy` is not null coz im appoint it in inspector
4 no im not, coz i need to disable a this `gameobject` `boxcollider`, not at `other`, being here as a `player`
3 this comment i don't understand, but also thanks for all

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand what you mean with `animation` ... The component or the clip?

Comment: To 4: but if this is the Player object why should the `other.gameObject.tag` be `Player` than?

Comment: The clip
My `player` (`other`) `BoxCollider2D` have `InTrigger` flag, and if he touch `gameObject` component, the `gameObject` must destroyed and play the animation was he.. destroyed. seems easy, but unity3d doesen't think so
I'm new to unity, and I still think I'm asking some funny things.